# How to update characteristic in Bluetooth Core when I am already connected?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

When i connect my central to peripheral device i use this function to capture the characteristic I'm interested in

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
        for characteristic in characteristics {
            //print("Characteristic: \(characteristic)")
            if characteristic.uuid == targetCharacteristicUUID {
                targetCharacteristic = characteristic
                print("Added characteristic: \(characteristic)")
                
                //Provo a richiedere un informazione appena mi sottoscrivo alla caratteristica
                self.readCharacteristicValue()
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to made the same when I'm already connected but i don't know how. I use this function:

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didModifyServices invalidatedServices: [CBService]) {}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You get the characteristic when you connect as you have shown. You can keep the value until,you disconnect. When you reconnect you do the same thing again. If your peripheral changes it's services you can just call `discoverServices` again

Comment: In the second function i want rescan all characteristic and keep the target characteristic, same the first function. But i don't know how to make this, becouse I don't have service variable like first.

Comment: You have to call `discoverServices` again and then discover the characteristics of the service

Comment: Ah okay.. It was so simple, I was getting messed up for no reason. Thank you so much